# HTML Inline Flex not adapting to main class

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's the problem i'm facing.

I'm trying to create two container under the class of `content4` with `imagesetter` as the class.
The motive is to move the margin `25%` width from the left.

Now it looks for the picture is working fine.
But as for the text, i've tried all kind of display. The second text just doesn't want align to the right.

CSS:

```
#content4 {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.imghalf{
width:35%;
margin-left: 100px;

}

.imgsetter{
    padding-left:10%;
}

.t5 {
  font-family:actor;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:26px;
  margin-left:100px;
}

.t6 {
  display:inline-flex;
  font-family:actor;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:26px;
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content4" class="imgsetter">
<img class="imghalf" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x300.png" />  
<img class="imghalf" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x300.png" />

<p class="t5">This is how we do it at stackoverflow man</p>
<p class="t6">This is how we do it at stackoverflow man</p>
</div>
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/LLYvEm

Just suggestion from the pros, 
Should i create 4 container with width of 25% each and park it under `content4`?
This is to tackle the responsiveness .

Comment: Don't you mean flex? I've never heard of flux.

Comment: @noahnu, it's flex. My bad for the typo :(

Comment: no luck sad. it's kinda tough :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it by using changing the method to inline block:

HTML :

```
<div id="content4" class="imgsetter">
<img class="imghalf" src="Projects/Sojo/Documentation/Slice/01_Home/itenarythumb01.png" />  
<img class="imghalf" src="Projects/Sojo/Documentation/Slice/01_Home/itenarythumb02.png" />

<p class="t5 imghalf">5 Days 4 Nights Tokyo Free & Easy Travel!</p>
<p class="t5 imghalf">6 Days 5 Nights Nagano Nature Adventure </p>
</div>
```

CSS changes:

```
.t5 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family:actor;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:26px;
  margin-left:25%;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

Explanation : I added two class based on the

. So it will inherit the container that was divided by the `margin-left 25%`